# Calling function in Ionic controller after data loaded

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, firebase

I am pulling data from firebase and depending on the data, I adjust show a different image. My data is taking time to return and the conditional I wrote doesn't do anything because it runs before the data returns. How do I call the function after my data loads? I tried everything on the [ionicView Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/). I also tried window.onload but that doesn't work. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/files/0/" + $stateParams.theId);

firebaseRef.once('value', function(dataSnapshot){

var dumData = dataSnapshot.val().data;
//this is just an integer 

    if (dumData > 3){
        document.getElementById("pic").style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/pic2.png';
    }

  //Please ignore syntax errors as they do not exist in original code
```

Comment: Please post some code, at least how you are fetching data and showing data so that we can help.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Avinash , I added some snippet. Thank you

Comment: @J.Doe i thing you used the callback or promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not related with ionic.

`once` returns a promise. So you should use the `success` callback to handle your data.

From [Firebase `once` documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/once.html):

```
// Provide a failureCallback to be notified when this
// callback is revoked due to security violations. 
firebaseRef.once('value',
  function (dataSnapshot) { 
  // code to handle new value
}, function (err) {
  // code to handle read error
});
```